# resource offer showing less memory than added in mesos

Tags: cluster-computing, mesos

I am currently exploring mesos. I have set up mesos cluster with one slave node added. The hardware added is 1 cpu-core, 2 GB RAM. but at mesos UI it is showing 1 cpu-core, and 1001 MB RAM. It is showing approximately 1GB less RAM. Can any one knows where remaining 1GB RAM is getting utilized ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't [specify](https://open.mesosphere.com/reference/mesos-slave/) via `resources` how much RAM a Mesos Slave (now: Agent) is supposed to use the default kicks in, see the [Mesos containerizer](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/slave/containerizer/containerizer.cpp#L98-L114) for details.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a valuable information. While going through ( second link ) another doubt came in my mind that suppose, if we add 10 slaves of above configuration then only 50% of memory will be utilized leaving 50% free which is against of "better utilization of resources".  If I am wrong, please clarify me..

Comment: I'd argue that in production you'd configure your Mesos Agents in a sensible way (that is >> 2GB RAM and explicit config of resource usage), but yeah, you're correct, in your setup it would (but again, I guess I'm trying to say this wouldn't make sense in my books ;)